# How to add ten new columns to SQL table with 1000+ records in it without losing any single record

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am looking for query that I can use to add ten new boolean columns to existing table without effecting anything else in database. Also by default these boolean columns should be set to true as default.

Looking for best practices.

**Edit**

"Also by default these boolean columns should be set to true as default."

Sorry I meant to say that for records already exists new column should have value set as true, there shouldn't be any default value as I will set it myself.

Comment: It's rare to need more than a few `bit` columns (what I assume you're after - SQL Server has no boolean type) in a table, so best practices may involve examining why you're adding so many to the table - do they actually model some kind of status, or something that may be better stored as distinct rows in a separate table?

Comment: its just a weird need by my client

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just add the columns via an ALTER statement:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD MyColumn bit NULL
```

or not nullable with a default value:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD MyColumn bit NOT NULL default 1
```

thats it for MSSQL.

EDIT:

if you want to add multiple columns at a time you can use:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD MyCol1 bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, MyCol2 bit NULL
GO
```

the "go" completes the batch.

Comment: You might also want to give the syntax for adding multiple columns.